VHDL when else interpretation
Is it correct to have such a code where the output depends on three input signals, but the signal C is not relevant in each case? So I do not specify this C in every case.
I mean, for example, is the first case fulfilled when A and B are = 0 and then there will be X1 on Y or is this however treated as the last else and the output will be '0'.
Y <= X1 when (A = '0' and B = '0') else           
     X1 when (A = '0' and B = '1') else           
     X2 when (A = '1' and B = '1' and C = '0') else 
     X1 when (A = '1' and B = '1' and C = '1') else 
     X1 when (A = '1' and B = '0') else           
     '0';


It's called conditional signal assignment (e.g. IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.5.3 Conditional signal assignments) and there's an equivalent if statement.

Condition expressions are syntactically distinguishable here from reserved words when and else, in if statements by reserved words if and then. Parentheses separating conditions from reserved words are not necessary in VHDL.

Yes.
You could also rewrite it as:
Y <= X1 when (A = '0' or B = '0' or C = '1') else 
     X2 when C = '0' else             
     '0';

I would probably ignore mapping the 'X' conditions to '0' and simply write:
Y <= X1 when (A = '0' or B = '0' or C = '1') else X2 ;

if you are worried about X's in RTL you can instead do:
assert not (is_X(A) or is_X(B) or is_X(C)) report "found an X on an input" severity warning ; 

That said the point of VHDL is to write your code in its most readable form and let the synthesis tools do the reduction of the equation - if that is your first equation then leave it that way.
